# URL returned by WYSIWYG is wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg

I'm using wysiwyg editor to insert image but it return full URL path inserted of media URL in content area.

WYSIWYG is returning path like

```
<img alt="" src="mydomain.com/media/wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg">
```

but iI want a URL like

```
<img src="{{media url=wysiwyg/the-picture.jpg"}}" alt="" />
```

any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ohh i got answer Myself
Login to Admin.

```
Go to System > Configuration > Content Management (Under General) > WYSIWYG Options
```

‘`Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog’ – Select “No”`

Answer (score 0):

the error is due to `Mage::getBaseUrl('media')` does not pass the store parameter !

To solve this bug, change in :

```
app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Wysiwyg/Images.php
```

Find function : `getImageHtmlDeclaration`

and change :

```
$mediaPath = str_replace(Mage::getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);
```

by

```
$mediaPath = str_replace(mage::app()->getStore($this->_storeId)->getBaseUrl('media'), '', $fileurl);
```